# How to get 6 random product from a catregory in magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection

I want to get 6 random product from same category on product page in magento 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the method `orderRand()` which can be applied to the select of a collection for getting random sorting.

For example in product page context you can create a block like the following, add it to your layout where you need it, and get the collection of the 6 random products calling the method `getRandomItems()` from your template. Please note: The approach works if the `current_category` is set. That's the case if your product page is called with category path. If you don't have the `current_category` in your context, please load the category you need. Anyway if no category is given the method returns 6 products randomly from the whole assortment.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Randomproducts extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct
{
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );
    }

    public function getRandomItems()
    {
        $category = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category');
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->setPageSize(6);
        if ($category){
            $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
        }
        $collection->getSelect()->orderRand();

        return $collection->getItems();
    }
}
```

I hope that helps. Feedback would be nice :-)